# Is there a way to capture a screen of Vaadin so an email can be created

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-charts

I would like to use Vaadin to display live stats of some systems.  The requirements require that we send out an email with the stats upon certain conditions.  I was wondering if it is possible to do a "screen capture" to an image that can then be sent in a email.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/charts.advanced.html#charts.advanced.export) states:

> ## 18.7.1. Server-Side Rendering and Exporting
>
> In addition to using charts in Vaadin UIs, you may also need to provide them as images or in downloadable documents. Vaadin Charts can be rendered on the server-side using a headless JavaScript execution environment, such as PhantomJS.
>
> Vaadin Charts supports a HighCharts remote export service, but the SVG Generator based on PhantomJS is almost as easy to use and allows much more powerful uses.

It continiues with the description, how to do this.

Comment: The question is how to capture a screen of Vaadin, not a Vaadin Chart.

Comment: @Abbas why then add a vaadin-charts tag in the first place?  yet the part about phantomjs holds true for any web application